# Double integral $\int \int (\log x) (\log y)/F(x,y) dx dy$: elegant way?

Tags: integration

I need to evaluate (or, if that is not feasible, bound well) some integrals of the type

$$\mathop{\int \int}_{(x,y)\in U} \frac{\log x \log y}{F(x,y)} dx dy,$$
where $U = \{(x,y)\in [1,\infty)^2: F(x,y)>R\}$, $R$ is positive, and $F(x,y)$ is one of the following:

1. $F(x,y) = x^{5/3} y^{5/3} \max(x,y)$
2. $F(x,y) = x^{5/3} y^{5/3} (x+y)$
3. $F(x,y) = x^{5/3} y^{5/3} |x-y|$
4. $F(x,y) = x^{5/3} y^{5/3} \max(|x-y|,1)$.

My main concern is: how to do this without inflicting a painful mess on myself and the reader?

Cross-posted in StackOverflow (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4338486/double-integral-elegant-way/4338575#4338575), where I showed how to do case $1$ using the substitution $u=x y$ and suffering. The only smarter thing I can think of (also pointed out by another contributor there) is to express
$$\mathop{\mathop{\int \int}_{(x,y)\in U}}_{x<y} \frac{\log x \log y}{F(x,y)} dx dy =
\mathop{\mathop{\int \int}_{(x,y)\in U}}_{x<y} \frac{\log x \log y}{x^{5/3} y^{8/3}} dx dy = \bigg(\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \frac{\partial}{\partial b} \mathop{\mathop{\int \int}_{(x,y)\in U}}_{x<y} \frac{dx dy}{x^{a} y^{b}} dx \bigg)\bigg|_{(a,b)=(5/3,8/3)},$$
say. (I'm sure this is extremely standard.)